# Plot with logarithmic y axis having x axis type as datetime in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to construct a semi log plot with logarithmic y axis. My x axis type is datetime.
In general, to accomplish this, one can use semilogy command. Below written sample code gives a gist of what I would like to get done:

```
clear;clc;close
StartDate = datenum('12-Oct-2012 16:50:00');
EndDate = datenum('12-Oct-2012 17:50:00');
NoOfYAxisDataPoints=20;
NoOfTickMarks=5;
xAxisData = linspace(StartDate,EndDate,NoOfYAxisDataPoints);
yAxisData=linspace(1,25,NoOfYAxisDataPoints);
figure
semilogy(xAxisData,yAxisData)
xTickData = linspace(StartDate,EndDate,NoOfTickMarks);
ax = gca;
ax.XTick = xTickData;
datetick('x','HH:MM','keepticks')
```

Here both x and y axis data are double type.
But how do I accomplish my objective if the x axis data is not double, but datetime type as shown here:

```
Year = 2012;Month = 10;Day = 12;
Hours = 16;Minutes=(50:5:110)';Seconds= 00;
Time=datetime(Year,Month,Day,Hours, Minutes, Seconds);
figure
plot(Time,linspace(1,25,13))
xTickData = linspace(datenum(Time(1)),datenum(Time(end)),NoOfTickMarks);
ax = gca;
ax.XTick = xTickData;
datetick('x','HH:MM','keepticks')
```

When I change plot to semilogy, I am getting an error message “Error using semilogy. Non-numeric data is not supported in 'Line'”. But, the documentation of [semilogy](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/semilogy.html) states that “The values in Xn can be numeric, datetime, duration, or categorical values. The values in Yn must be numeric.”. Even though my x axis values are datetime type, I am getting this error. What am I doing wrong? How do I accomplish this task?

I am using Matlab2016a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your Matlab version does not support `datetime` as x-axis for `semilogy`. At least R2019b works fine for me. You can easily change y-scale after `plot`:

```
ax.YScale = 'log';
```